# Improving the performance of MKOverlayViews

Tags: ios, performance, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387951/mkoverlayview-performance) a while ago about boosting the speed at which MKOverlays are added to an MKMapView by using threading during their creation, but I soon realized that the part of the process that was really dragging me down was not the creation of the overlays, but their addition to the map. Creating many overlays (even 3000+) takes an acceptable amount of time, but adding them all to the map takes far too long (15 seconds).

---

I know 'what are your favorite' questions usually aren't considered 'right' for Stack Overflow, but I think this question is okay because although it is subjective in a way, there is still a 'right' answer- the one that provides significant changes in the performance of an MKMapView with lots of MKOverlayViews.

Basically, I'd love to know if anyone has any tips or tricks (any at all) for tuning the speed of the addition of many different MKOverlays to a map view. Right now my alternative is combining them all into one big line, which is much faster, but then I lose the ability to treat each segment as an individual line (i.e. being able to show a callout for each segment), which is one of the cooler features in the app, so I'd really like to find a way to make this work. Right now, all of the lines load, given enough time, but even after, scrolling is a nightmare.

I'd really like to hear your thoughts! Thanks!